# Tile boxes of differnet size responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have some problems with my responsive design.

I have 20 boxes like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shoyad/bbwkc/1/embedded/result/)

I want to do responsive with mediaqueries

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 783px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 524px) {

}
```

But I can't control the boxes in my design. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shoyad/bbwkc/1/)

Comment: Have a look at [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and this article http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some solutions like these:

- http://purecss.io/grids/
- http://semantic-ui.com/

Or try adding a specific width to each box for each media query.

Comment: It looks as though @Vlad-Mihai is on the right track with the 2nd option, but rather than an explicit width for each block, have 2 classes: wide and narrow; and assign a percentage width for each class, for each media query.

Answer (score 0):

I just put these lines of code into the CSS area and it worked outstandingly:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1500px) {
    .block {width: 250px}  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .block {width: 100px}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If only the width needs to be responsive you can work with `max-width` and `width` in percentages. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/bbwkc/3/

```
.block_main {
    max-width:750px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

And so on.